# Continuity of p? - norms?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm studying some analysis and I've came upon a problem I couldn't come up with a solution. Let $E$ be a real vector space. A norm is a function $\| \cdot\|: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:

1. $\|x\| = 0 \iff x = 0$
2. $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$
3. $\|\lambda x\| = |\lambda| \| x\|$

This function induces a topology that $\mathcal{B} = \{ B(x,\varepsilon) = \{y\in E: \|x - y\| < \varepsilon\}\}_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R},\; x \in E}$ is basis.

If we replace the second condition with $\|x+ y\|^p \leq \|x\|^p + \|y\|^p$, $p \in (0, 1)$, then it is continuous with the topology it produces?

In other words, the function $\| \cdot\|: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies 1, 3 and $\|x+y\|^p \leq \|x\|^p+\|y\|^p$ with $p\in (0,1)$, is continuous with the topology on E that has $\{y\in E: \|x-y\|< \varepsilon\}$ as basis and the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried with a p-norm $\|f\|_p =  \left(\int_\Omega |f|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, $p \in (0,1)$ but I went blank. Any solutions?

Comment: The p-norm you tried in the last sentence is not a norm (try constant functions), people usually define $\|f\|_p = \int_\Omega |f|^p$ for $p\in (0,1)$

Comment: It is still continuous with respect to the topology you described - the proof is basically the same. Alternatively, you could just use what LNT suggested - $d(x, y) = ||x - y||^p$ is actually a metric, and the topology is just the one induced by this metric.

Comment: @LNT Yes, my bad. But I don't see that $\| \cdot \|$  is continuous. I only see that $\| \cdot \|^p$ is continuous. There is an argument that says $\| \cdot \|^p$ continuous $ \implies \| \cdot \|$ continuous?